# How to read JSON data from an Android app in C# Rest service

Tags: c#, android, json, rest, post

I'm fairly new to android development and working with REST services to allow communication between apps and databases on my server.

I've been working on an application that pulls information relating to tickets logged on our system. My android application is able to successfully consume the REST service to get data from my database, however I'm having a really difficult time getting my REST service to accept JSON formatted data from my application to update an existing ticket or create a new one.

My REST service is written in C#

Below is a sample of my GET request which works perfectly because there are a few parameters and are withing the length accepted by a URL:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "incidentAgent/{agent}/{incID}")] //PASS A 0 incID IF SELECTING ALL
    Stream AgentIncidentListing(string agent, string incID);
```

This is my android app code to generate the JSON string and send the POST request to my web service:

```
public void updateIncidents(View v){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                //Declare and initialize text views from the layout
                TextView tvidIncidents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIncidentID);
                TextView tvResolution = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResolution );
                TextView tvJobCardNo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJobCardNo );
                TextView tvActualHours = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvActualHours );
                TextView tvBudgetHours = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvBudgetHours );
                TextView tvTaskDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTaskDesc );
                TextView tvOutline = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvOutline );
                TextView tvProject = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvProject );
                TextView tvIncidentType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvIncidentType );
                TextView tvStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStatus );
                TextView tvCustomer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCustomer );
                TextView tvIncidentNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvIncidentNumber );
                TextView tvDueBy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDueDate);

                URL url = new URL(updateURI);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("iIncidentStatusID", tvStatus.getText());
                jsonParam.put("iDebtorID", tvCustomer.getText());
                jsonParam.put("cOutline", tvOutline.getText());
                jsonParam.put("iIncidentTypeID", tvIncidentType.getText());
                jsonParam.put("iProjectID", tvProject.getText());
                jsonParam.put("ufINCBHours", tvBudgetHours.getText());
                jsonParam.put("ufINCAH", tvActualHours.getText());
                jsonParam.put("ucINCJN", tvJobCardNo.getText());
                jsonParam.put("ucINCTaskDescription", tvTaskDesc.getText());
                jsonParam.put("ucINCResolution", tvResolution.getText());
                jsonParam.put("dDueBy", tvDueBy.getText());
                jsonParam.put("idIncidents", tvidIncidents.getText());
                Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

                os.flush();
                os.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

The problem that I'm having is I have absolutely no clue on how to handle this POST request on my REST service. this is what I have thus far:

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,

     UriTemplate = "updateIncData")]

    void UpdateJsonIncident(RequestData rData);
```

The RequestData class:

```
 public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to be able to read the JSON string returned by my android app and assign the relevant values to my insert or update statement in the UpdateJsonIncident() function to affect my database accordingly.

I've tried many things but can't get this to work. After sitting at my desk for the 2nd day(currently 11 hours straight) I feel like requesting assistance here is my last resort and hope that someone can assist me.

Answer (score 0):

So finally made a breakthrough. Turns out all I had to do was the following:

1) I created a class called "IncidentData" like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace xxxxx.Classes
{
    [DataContract]

    public class IncidentData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string idIncidents { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string IncidentStatus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string cOurRef { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string cOutline { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string IncidentType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Project { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string BudgetedHours { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ActualHours { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string JobCardNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Resolution { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string dDueBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2) Changed my operation contract like so:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "/UpdateJsonIncident")]

    bool UpdateJsonIncident(IncidentData incident);
```

3) Now, all I need to do to access my data in the UpdateJsonIncident function is as follows:

```
        public bool UpdateJsonIncident(IncidentData incident) {

         string xxx = incident.cOutline // etc...
    }
```

I hope this helps save someone else a lot of time if they are faced with the same problem.